# Need help with my proof about connected set

Tags: real-analysis

I try to prove following:

$E \subseteq \mathbb R$ is connected if and only if for $a,b \in E$ and $a < c < b$ it follow that $c \in E$.

Definition of connceted: A set $E$ is connected if it is not the union of two nonempty separated sets.

Please can you help me with my proof?

$\implies$: Assume $a<c<b$ with $a,b \in E$ but $c \notin E$. Then $E\cap (-\infty,c), (c,\infty)\cap E$ are two separated sets with union equal to $E$.

$\Longleftarrow$: Assume $E=A\cup B$ where $A,B$ are separated and not empty. Let $a\in A,b\in B$ and without loss of generality $a<b$. If all $c$ in $(a,b)$ are in $E$ then ...

Is it possible to finish the argument? I tried but failed.

Comment: Your definition is wrong. It must be: "a set $\;E\;$ in a topological space is connected iff it is not the disjoint union of two non-empty **open** subsets".

Comment: Well @bof , since I am talking of $\;E\;$ without relating it to anything else, it is open/closed **in** $\;E\;$, of course. About the separated thing: the only one using it, as far as I could see, is Willard's Topology book. Also see my last comment below my answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio From John M. H. Olmsted's *Real Variables* p. 77. **Definition VII.** Two sets are **separated** if and only if they are disjoint and neither contains a limit point of the other. **Definition VIII.** A set $A$ is said to be **split into two parts** $B$ and $C$ if and only if $B$ and $C$ are disjoint and every point of $A$ belongs either to $B$ or to $C$. **Definition IX.** A set $A$ is **connected** if and only if it cannot be split into two separated nonempty parts.

Comment: Hmmm, a book from 1959...anyway, I'd like to see a definition of *connectedness* that doesn't mention "closed" or "open". Just "separated", even accepting the definition of separated, is, I believe, incomplete.

Comment: BTW, that definition of Olmsted seems to make $\;[0,1]\;$ disconnected, or I'm misunderstandign something. Again, please do see my last comment below my answer here.

Comment: I know that, @bof and that's precisely what I wrote in my first comment to you...am I really being that unclear? Please check again the OP and see nowhere there "open" is mentioned !

Comment: Oh, apparently the "limit point" thing, @bof...I see. Anyway, the non-writing about open/closed remaing, as far as I can see.

Comment: So you're saying @bof that if a write "separated sets" in topology stuff *automatically* it is to be understood they're open (yes, **in** the inherited space or whatever) ?

Comment: @bof Isn't the definition of "separated" within topology already implying disjoint?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

After you correct your definition of (dis)conneceted space (set), then: the first part is correct, and for the other direction $\;\Longleftarrow\;$ :

Suppose $\;A,B\neq\emptyset\;$ are open, disjoint and $\;E=A\cup B\;$ . Suppose first that we have

$$\;A=(r,s)\;,\;\;B=(t,u)\;,\;\;r<s<t<u\;\implies\;$$

since $\;(r,s)\cap(t,u)=\emptyset\;$ then there exists $\;s<c<t\;$ (why?), and clearly $\; c\notin E\;$ , contradiction.

Now generalize the above taking into account that a subset of the real line is open iff it is the union of open *intervals*. You may want to distinguish between bounded and unboudned $\;E\;$ , too, as thi might make the proof easier.

Comment: Why is my defintion wrong? [Separated or clopen are equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space)?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, @blue . Could you please direct me to some acceptable definition of "separated set"? I've never heard of it...

Comment: Click on link to definition of separated set in point 5 in the link above. Is it not acceptable?

Comment: Point 5 in your link is "local connectedness" and I couldn't see anything about separated there, @blue...but who cares: where **did you** take your definition of connected space??

Comment: No no no point 5 in definition of connected space!

Comment: @blue Oh, I see...well, according to that "equivalent definition" of connected, and since we can write $\;[0,1]=[0,1/2)\cup [1/2,1]\;$ and these two are "separated spaces" as defined there, then the unit interval isn't connected...?

Comment: Anyway, the above answer stands, this or that definition...

Comment: Yes, I already acknowledged that in *the other* comments, @bof . Read there.

Comment: I am sorry! I corrected the definition!

Comment: Why can you assume $A,B$ are open?